# Tutorial for Pascal/Delphi for C++-Coders

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm a C++-Programmer. But now i have to learn Pascal/Pascal. Are there any websites, documents around that can teach someone with my knowledge the difference?

Comment: Now that's a first: someone moving from C++ to Pascal! In all these years how programming has become topsy-turvy!

Comment: no i'm writing c++ in my free time, but now in school we have to learn pascal ...

Comment: Well, if you're taking a class on it you should be able to learn the language pretty quickly with an existing C++ background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be too difficult to pick up.  C's design was influenced by ALGOL and Pascal, so the semantics and logical flow are going to be pretty familiar.  You can get an overview of the differences between basic Pascal and basic C [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Pascal_and_C).

But you tagged this as Delphi and you mentioned C++, which implies that you'll need information on OOP techniques.  Try [this article](http://www.marcocantu.com/papers/ooplang.htm) or [this one](http://www.derangedcoder.net/programming/general/comparingObjectOrientedFeatures.html), which compare object-oriented programming in Delphi with C++ and other languages.  Both are a bit dated, but most of the basic information in them still applies today.

If you have any specific questions about language features, feel free to ask them here, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4):

You can check [**Essential Pascal**](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/) written by Marco Cantù, is a introduction to the Pascal programming language. you can download a **free** copy from [here](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/EssentialPascal.zip).

[image]

Another excellent site for beginners, is [**Delphi Basics**](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/), this web site provides help and reference for the fundamentals of the Delphi language. It gives an introduction to the Delphi Object Oriented Language for newcomers.

Answer (score 2):

A website that helped me a lot when I learned Delphi was http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/. I still use it. It presents common methods in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381754/where-can-i-find-good-beginner-level-delphi-tutorials-online/1381861#1381861) on beginner guides to Delphi.  It has some good links included that may be rather simplistic for you, but can still take you a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Marco Cantu (mentioned in several answers) also has a book series called "Mastering Delphi."  It is a great (maybe only) top to bottom resource.  Everything Delphi is in it.  But the last edition is for 2005.  Four versions of Delphi have been released since.  There are a couple of update sheets available from Marco's website (D2006 was mostly a bug fix of 2005).  And Marco also has the Handbook series, but that is aimed at people who already know Delphi and are looking for help on the newest improvements.

Personally, Delphi is my favorite language.  I hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

your name sounds german so you might wanne check these pages out 
[delphipraxis](http://www.delphipraxis.net)

it's not really a comparison for cpp and delphi/pascal but you'll find a lot of information

due to me being a new user i'm not able to post a second link. but search google for delphi forum..

Answer (score 0):

The Free Pascal documentation is another great resource:

http://www.freepascal.org/docs.var